# How to allow deleting all chars in React Material-UI Input Field component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using an Input Field from React @material-ui/core. When I use
`type="number"` and set `inputProps={{ min: 1, max: 99 }}` user cannot delete the last digit/char.

It is a bit of an UX fail, because for example when I input 8, I want to press backspace and then 5. But It won't allow me to delete the last char.

I have tried a few hacks, but I want to resolve it with some standard way or use different component.

Could anyone guide me on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Can you provide example,  i created: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-jurim you can edit to demostrate the issue

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Could you please show how you're trying to implement the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't delete the last char is because you set a minimum value of 1.

If you do it like above then you're not getting numbers anymore for the value, you're getting strings. But agreed, it's not material UI.

A better way to handle it is to check if there is a value and convert that to a Number, otherwise pass an empty string. For ex. in an `onChange` handler for a controlled component:

```
onChange={(e) => setField(e.target.name, e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) : '')}
```

Answer (score 1):

for me it wasn't material UI it was the default input and this fixed it:

```
<Input type="number" value={number.toString()} />
```